# regexp get matches by group

Tags: go

I want to parse a string and get the substring inside two quotes

## subject

```
query="tag1 tag2"
```

## pattern

```
query="([a-z ]*)"
```

## result

```
tag1 tag2
```

## code

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)

var re = regexp.MustCompile(`query="([a-z ]*)"`)

func main() {
  match  := re.FindStringSubmatch(`query="tag1 tag2"`)
  result := make(map[string]string)
  for i, name := range re.SubexpNames() {
     result[name] = match[i]
  }
  fmt.Printf("by name: %v\n", result)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/voKpOlcc8J

## update

string

```
query="tag1 tag2 tag3" foo="wee"
```

matches
`tag1` `tag2` `tag3`

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    var str string = `query="tag1 tag2 tag3" foo="wee"`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`query="(([a-z0-9]+) ?)*"`)
    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    if len(match) == 0 {
        fmt.Print("no matches")
    } else {
        result := make(map[string]string)
        for i, name := range re.SubexpNames(){
            result[name] = match[i]
        }
        fmt.Print(result)
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/8vieH4eDd1

Comment: `SubexpNames()` is a method of the regular expression, it does not apply to the results of a Find...Match operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the whole tag string and then `Split()` it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var str string = `query="tag1 tag2 tag3" foo="wee"`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`query="(.+?)"`)
    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)

    if len(match) == 2 {
        fmt.Println(strings.Split(match[1], " "))
    }
}
```

Output: `[tag1 tag2 tag3]`

Answer (score 2):

First off, the pattern will not match the digits. You might want to change it to:

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`query="(.*)"`)
```

Then, in order to get the substring, you can just use `FindStringSubmatch`:

```
match := re.FindStringSubmatch(`query="tag1 tag2"`)
if len(match) == 2 {
    fmt.Printf("Found: [%s]\n", match[1])
} else {
    fmt.Println("No match found", match)
}
```

**Output:**

> Found: [tag1 tag2]

Then, in order to split the string into seperate tags, I recommend using [`strings.Split`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split)

Comment: Have updated my question.. I need to match each tag `tag1` `tag2` and `tag3` indeside `query=""`

Comment: @clarkk Well, if you had read my answer, you'd see that I recommended using `strings.Split` to handle that. Exactly what later was used in the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The regexp does not accept digits, `s/[a-z ]/[a-z0-9 ]/`

http://play.golang.org/p/ov_zoxBenV